# SharePoint Not Installed Error with VS 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to create a new SharePoint project in my virtual machine. it has SharePoint 2013 installed. 
I am using visual studio 2010 ultimate version.
Every time i try to create a new empty SharePoint, web part or any SharePoint project it says. 
**A SharePoint server is not installed on this computer. A share Point server must me installed to work with SharePoint projects**

but i have SharePoint 2013 installed. 
can we use VS 2010 to create SharePoint projects in a VM with SP2013 installed. 
I just installed the office developer tools for VS 2010 as well. But still i get the same results. 
Any ideas. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This link describes the problem and how to fix it](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/4b0c01f5-8a20-4d73-a3a9-5f6f2e073fc8/cant-connect-to-sharepoint-server-2013-with-visual-studio-2010?forum=sharepointdevelopment)

So, have you installed `Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2012`? The default SharePoint project templates come with VS2012 is for SharePoint 2010 and will not work in SharePoint 2013 Server.

Also you need to make sure the site against which you are developing farm solution doesn't use developer template (rather user team site template).